# MySQL Like search special chars escape

Tags: mysql, sql-like

yet another MySQL `LIKE` search which doesn't return anything

I have contents in my MySQL DB which hold "\'"

However I cannot find them as my query returns either nothing or too many items depending on how i format the like parameter.

This doesn' reurns anything:

```
SELECT element 
FROM `elements` 
WHERE body LIKE '%\\\'%' 
LIMIT 5
```

This return almost all items because many item hold the single quote char

```
SELECT element 
FROM `elements` 
WHERE body LIKE '%\'%' 
LIMIT 5
```

This doesn't work:

```
SELECT element_id 
FROM `element_body` 
WHERE element_body LIKE '%|\|'%' ESCAPE'|' 
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: The first one is *very* close. It's only missing another backslash and another single quote. Needs to be **four** backslash characters and **two** single quote characters "**`'%\\\\''%'`**".  See my answer for a demonstration, and more detailed explanation.

Comment: thanks spencer7593 for your long feedback, it helped a lot
however we couldn't make the LIKE '%\\\\''%' statement work, so we used a REGEX :

SELECT * FROM elementbody WHERE elementbody REGEXP '\\\\''' 

and it did the work

cheers

Comment: I'm not sure why the `LIKE '%\\\\''%'` didn't work for you, to return rows that contain "**`\'`**" (a literal backslash followed by a literal quote.) Here's a simple demonstration that shows that it works:  [**SQL Fiddle** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a7199/1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a7199/1). The same rules that apply to string literals in LIKE also apply in `REGEXP`. In the more general case, there are a lot more "special characters" in a regular expression pattern that need to be escaped. (I offered a solution for `LIKE` because that's what the question asked.)

Answer (score 2):

To get a `LIKE` comparison to match "**`\'`**" (a literal backslash character followed by a literal single quote, that can be done, but it does require some careful attention to escaping.

The biggest problem is that MySQL uses the backslash character in a string literal as an "escape" character... e.g. `\n` represents a single newline character.

Here's a demonstration.

```
    SELECT t.foo
         , t.foo LIKE '%\\\\''%'  AS `match_`
      FROM ( 
             SELECT 'abc\\''def' AS `foo`
             UNION ALL SELECT 'gh\\i\\j'
             UNION ALL SELECT 'k\\lm''n'
           ) t
```

The result of the `LIKE` comparison is returned as the second column. A value of `1` indicates TRUE, a value of `0` indicates FALSE.)

```
    foo       match_  
    --------  ------
    abc\'def       1
    gh\i\j         0
    k\lm'n         0
```

---

Let's unpack that a bit.

To represent a single quote within a string literal, we need to use *two* single quotes. As an example:

```
    SELECT 'I''m home'    --> I'm home
```

To get a literal backslash within a string literal, we need a *two* backslashes. The first backslash starts a normal MySQL "escape sequence", the second backslash is the character that's escaped. For example:

```
    SELECT 'a\\b'         --> a\b
```

In the `LIKE` comparison, a backslash character is considered an "escape" character. We'd use that before a `'%'` or `'_'` (percent or underscore character, which are normally interpreted as wild cards) to have those interpreted as literal characters we want to match.

To get the `LIKE` comparison to match a literal backslash character, we need *two* backslash characters. As we just demonstrated, to get a backslash character in a string literal requires *two* backslashes. So we need a total of **four** backslash characters.

Comment: A single quote character can also be "escaped" with a backslash, so a series of *five* backslashes and *one* single quote would probably also work. (The *two* single quotes approach to representing a single quote works in other databases. The "backslash escape" business in a string literal is a peculiar to MySQL.)

Answer (score 1):

You may need to use the REGEXP operator.

```
SELECT element FROM elements WHERE body RLIKE '%\\%' LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 0):

The first approach should've worked I guess.

[This](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/string-literals.html) says that \ should be replaced by `'%\\%'`.

Remove the ' in the first query and try again!!

Comment: This would "match" a string ending with a percent sign, for example this would match `'2%'`. OP wants to match to a backslash character immediately followed by a single quote character.